# Fast editing in raster calculator -- adding lots of images together

Tags: python, raster, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I need to add pictures together to make one raster.

- In one session there are about 150 - 200 images (named randomly - see syntax example)
- There are about 50 sessions (named randomly)

Is there any way to use a configuration of raster calculator instead of clicking on img1 and then img2 and so on... In the map algebra window the syntax looks like:

> "A201200A.jpg" + "A201200L.jpg" + "A201200W.jpg" + "A201201I.jpg" + "A201201S.jpg" + "A201202F.jpg" + "A201202Q.jpg" + "A201203C.jpg" + "A201203M.jpg" + "A201203W.jpg" + "A201204I.jpg" + "A201204S.jpg" + "A201205F.jpg"

and so on...

Is there a fast way to prepare a command without clicking on an image and then + and clicking again on an image and then + and so on???

Comment: What product do you hope to produce?  There may be very efficient built-in methods to accomplish this.

Comment: @Jakub Why not use the Weighted Sum tool with weights all set to 1.0 (or 1 / n or anything so long as it's the same for each)? That way you can shove all 200 rasters in in one go. I' not sure if the tool works with jpg images though.

Comment: what environment/language(s) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

you could automate this with a loop in Python. Arcpy uses "lazy computing, so this will be evaluated when you save.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

imList = glob.glob("your_path/*.jpg")

outraster = raster(imList[0])
i=0
for im in imList:
    if i>0:
        outraster += raster(im)
    i+=1
outraster.save("outputname")
```